# Python Dash datatable formatting: using style_data_conditional for conditional formatting - red for negative values, green for positive values

Tags: python, datatables, plotly-dash

I am trying to achieve something that I thought would be straight-forward for Dash datatable, but it appears it's a little bit more complicated than I initially assumed.

I have a datatable with 10 columns whose values are all numeric, and whose names are timestamps in string format - as such, these names change over time (and thus I can't perform conditional formatting using hard-coded column names for the 'style_data_conditional' parameter of my Dash datatable).

As a result, I need a dynamic way of specifying that each cell for each one of these columns appears in red font for negative values and in green for positive values.

I thought I could use dictionary comprehension to generate a dynamically created list of conditional formatting rules - this code is syntactically incorrect but it should demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
style_data_conditional = ([

      {
        'if': {
          'column_id': fieldname,
          'filter_query': '{' + field_name + '} > 0'
        },
        'color': 'green'

      } for field_name in data_table.columns,

      {
        'if': {
          'column_id': fieldname,
          'filter_query': field_name + ' < 0'
        },
        'color': 'red'
      } for field_name in data_table.columns,
    ])
```

Would anyone have an idea of another approach that could be taken to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ignore me. I got it working. For anyone who runs into the same problem, my solution was:

```
    style_data_conditional =
      # Colour red when values are negative
      [
        {
          'if': {'column_id': field_name, 'filter_query': '{' + field_name + '}' + ' < 0'},
          'color': 'red'
        } for field_name in data_table.columns
      ]

      +

      [
        # Colour green when values are positive
        {
        'if': {'column_id': field_name, 'filter_query': '{' + field_name + '}' + ' > 0'},
        'color': 'green'
        } for field_name in data_table.columns
      ]

  )]
```

Thanks.